# Pointer to a pointer as an argument for functions that manipulate linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to brush up on my C and have been reviewing data structures and pointer manipulation.  Can someone please explain to me why it is necessary to use a pointer to a pointer for head in this linked list reverse function?  Since head is always dereferenced once (*head) in the function, couldn't we just accept a normal Node* as an argument to this function and forgo the dereferencing? Thanks in advance!

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    struct Node *next;
};



struct Node* reverse(struct Node** head){
    Node *parent = *head;
    Node *me = parent->next;
    Node *child = me->next;

    parent->next = NULL;
    while(child) {
        me->next = parent;
        parent = me;
        me = child;
        child = child->next;
    }
    me->next = parent;
    *head = me;
    return *head;
}
```

Comment: Note that this code is C, not C++

Comment: @Manu343726 The concept is still perfectly valid for C++ . I don't think you should have removed the C++ tag as the OP clearly stated he is working on C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not pass in a `Node**` argument and just used a `Node*` argument, then this line

```
 *head = me;
```

would need to be implemented as

```
 head = me;
```

But as `head` would then be passed **by value** this results in a **copy** of `head` being passed to the function. Then modification your function makea would ONLY apply to this copy and NOT the argument you pass.

Whenever you need a function to modify an argument you need to pass it by reference or via a pointer. In your case you need `Node**` to modify the `Node*` that it points to.

You could also use a reference to a `Node*` argument.

As a ridiculous example consider this function

```
void ChangePointer(int* x)
{
    x = NULL;
}

void ChangePointer_2(int** x)
{
    *x = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int* p = new int(1);
    ChangePointer(p); 
    // p is not NULL. The function changed the copy
    // of p because it was passed by value.

    ChangePointer_2(&p);
    // now p == NULL;
}
```

Comment: First, I believe you, and I know this to be true, but I'm just trying to understand properly.
So, if i used `Node*` as an argument, the _pointer_ to the node would be passed by value... Since this is still a pointer, why wouldn't changes in the function affect the actual argument passed in?

Comment: @MRT89 You could change things that the pointer **points** to via dereferencing, but not the value of the pointer itself (ie its address). Code up a function that takes a pointer argument (by value), and try setting it to NULL. When you examine the address of the argument that you passed once the function has returned, it will not be NULL. You changed the value of the copy, not the pointer itself.

Comment: @MRT89 I have added an example that I hope better illustrates what I am trying to say.